# How to get Ubuntu's latest repositories on elementry OS Luna?

Tags: linux

I know that ElementryOS luna is based off of the Ubuntu 12.10 LTS, and so the packages are outdated (ex: the sudo apt-get install gimp will get you 2.6 instead of 2.8) so how do i get the latest ubuntu package reposorories, and how do I add them?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update`?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't. Elementary  OS Luna is built on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and it is likely to be broken by installing newer packages. There is no guarantee that they will work at all.

As for being outdated, this is not correct. It is true that there are newer packages, however the older ones are still being maintained, which means that fixes are actively being produced and security patches applied for all packages managed by Canonical. After all, this is the meaning of the LTS = Long Term Support expression.

If you still want to try updating you system after this, knowing full well that you might break it badly, you may try adding the following lines to the /etc/apt/sources.list file, adjusting the location as per your needs:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ saucy partner
```

But remember: you have been **warned**.